# Google App Engine template loop through two variables

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

On Google app engine, I'd like to use two variables in a template for loop: I need to input, say, 10 items. If there are already some items in the datastore, then show them, otherwise, leave the field blank. How do I do it? Thanks.

BTW, I noticed that there is "multifor" in Django, but I don't know how to install it on GAE.

main.py:

```
def mainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    query = db.Query(Item)
    items = query.fetch(limit=10)
    template_values = {'range': range(10), 'items': items}
    common.render(handler, 'main.html', template_values)
```

main.html:

```
<form action=... method="post">
      {% for i in range; for item in items %}
        <input type="text" name="name" value="item.name">
      {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure which templating engine you are using, but what about creating a list of 10-elements and filling it with the results of your query? Something like:

```
my_list = [None for _ in range(10)]
```

Then, once you get your query results, add them to the list (the objects will be returned as a list of objects, so this is just a conceptual example):

```
>>> new_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> my_list[:len(new_list)] = new_list
>>> my_list
['one', 'two', 'three', None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Now when you pass `my_list` into the template:

```
<form action=... method="post">
      {% for item in my_list %}
        {% if item %}
           <input type="text" name="name" value="item.name">
        {% else %}
           <input type="text" name="<your_blank_value>" value="<your_blank>">
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find these ideas helpful as well

(1) If the loop in your template is

```
{% for item in items %}
```

then you can use the variable `{{forloop.counter0}}` or `{{forloop.counter1}}` to get the index of the loop.

(2) You can pass a Python list of tuples to your template and write the for loop this way:

```
{% for index, name in names %}
```